# how to I fix my table about distinct and count in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have trouble about my table and about my Count and Distinct

this for my RazorView

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Tahun</th>
            <th colspan="2">Jml. F1</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Jml. F2 PR</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Jml. F2 PE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sementara</th>
            <th>Tetap</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.rol_tb_form1List.Select(x => x.tgl_moc.Year).Distinct())
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item)</td>  
                </tr>
            }
        @foreach (var form1 in Model.rol_tb_form1List.Where(y => y.jenis_perubahan == "sementara").GroupBy(x => x.tgl_moc.Year))
            {
                <tr>
                     <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => form1).ToString().Count()</td>
                </tr>
            }
        @foreach (var form1 in Model.rol_tb_form1List.Where(y => y.jenis_perubahan == "tetap").GroupBy(x => x.tgl_moc.Year))
            {
                <tr>
                     <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => form1).ToString().Count()</td>
                </tr>
            }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

can someone fix my code about my table or my Count or my Distinct..

sorry about my bad english

this foy my Controller

```
public ActionResult Rekap()
    {
        Setting setting = new Setting();
        setting.rol_tb_form1List = db.rol_tb_form1.ToList();
        return View(setting);
    }
```

I just use a simple Controller but I dont know this right or not..

result for that code

[image]

I want value `19 18 42 49` in column Sementara and value `377 363 63 13` in column Tetap

this for my example data, this just example

[image]

and I want result for thats example is like this

[image]

Comment: Please describe your problem, with this code.

Comment: Its hard to tell what you wanting to display in your view, but the controller is responsible for sending the correct data to the view and your view should not contain any of those queries. Your view model should contain 3 properties that are the results of you queries.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Your list related queries should be in your controller and not polluting the view

Comment: I already fix my question @S3PP3L,

Comment: You have a header row with 4 columns and each `foreach` is creating a row with just one column (your code makes no sense and we cannot tell what you want to do)

Comment: sow, ho to I fix that, I must change my code in view or in controller ?.. Im newbie so I want to know abaout this problem @StephenMuecke

Comment: can you make some example or change my code, please @Niladri

Comment: @Ihsan Its impossible to help without knowing what a sample of your data is and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: I want value `19 18 42 49` in column Sementara and value `377 363 63 13` in column Tetap.. see the picture.. maybe I wrong in my controller but I dont know how @StephenMuecke

Comment: That means nothing to us (its just the result)! What is a sample of your data?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have many record in year 2013-2017 maybe 750++ record in table `rol_tb_form1` and column `jenis_perubahan` have 2 value is `tetap` and `sementara`, I want to count based on year, and show year with distinct

Comment: Just edit you question to show say sample 10 records, and what you expect the result of those to be (basically everything your doing here is wrong, but we cannot fix it without understanding what the data is and how you want it to be displayed)

Comment: @StephenMuecke done sir, I hope this can help me

Comment: ok sir, I always waiting for the answer, because I want to learn :) @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few principals that you should always follow:

1. Your controller is responsible for passing the correct data to the
   view (your views should not contain queries)
2. Create view models to represent the way you want the represent the
   data in the view

In you case you need a view model to represent your table, and to represent each row in your table

```
public class RowVM
{
    // Properties for each column
    public int Tahun { get; set; }
    public int Sementara { get; set; }
    public int Tetap { get; set; }
}
public class TableVM
{
    public Enumerable<RowVM> Rows { get; set; }
    .... // other properties as required to represent the table header, footer etc
}
```

Then in the GET method, change the query to return the data and project it into your view model

```
var data = db.rol_tb_form1.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.tgl_moc.Year).Select(x => new RowVM
{
    Tahun = x.Key,
    Sementara = x.Where(y => y.genis_perubahan == "sementara").Count(),
    Tetap = x.Where(y => y.genis_perubahan == "tetap").Count()
});
TableVM model = new TableVM
{
    Rows = data,
    ....
};
return View(model);
```

and the view is simply

```
@model TableVM
....
<table>
    <thead> .... </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in Model.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@row.Tahun<td>
                <td>@row.Sementara<td>
                <td>@row.Tetap<td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that I omitted the table headings because its not clear what your trying to do with your first image, but since the rows contain 3 columns, then you heading should also contain 3 columns.

Comment: thanks sir.. last, if I add 1 table, where i should add it,.. Must I add in viewmodel 1 table again ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment (the code I have shown is adding 1 table)

Comment: sorry, I mean if 2 table

Comment: There is nothing in your question about a 2nd table! (I can only answer your question)

Comment: hmm, oke sir, I am really grateful for your answer